# Convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a} \prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{1+i a}$ as $a \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using numerical simulation, I can see that 
$$
v(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a} \prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{1+i a}
$$
converges to some value $1<v(a)<2$ as $a \rightarrow 0$. However, I couldn't find bounding series to prove it. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong but for $a=\frac {1}{10}$, I get $v=1.05391$ and for $a=\frac {1}{100}$, I get $v=1.18772$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $v$ is between 1 and 2. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will denote $z = a^{-1}$ and $f(z) = v(a)$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
f(z)
&= z^{-1/2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z}{k + z}
 = z^{-1/2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{n}\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+n+1)} \\
&= z^{-1/2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{\Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{z}(1-x)^{n-1} \, dx \\
&= z^{1/2} \int_{0}^{1} x^{z} e^{z(1-x)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{e^{z}}{z^{z+1/2}} \int_{0}^{z} t^{z} e^{-t} \, dt. \qquad (t = zx)
\end{align*}

Now by noting that $ z! \sim \sqrt{2\pi} z^{z+1/2} e^{-z}$ and

$$ \int_{0}^{z} t^{z} e^{-t} \, dt \sim \frac{z!}{2} $$

as $z \to \infty$, it follows that

$$ \lim_{a\to 0^{+}} v(a) = \lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \approx 1.2533141373155002512\cdots. $$

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks a lot! I now found a more general version of this problem, but I don't think this method is applicable (or at least I wasn't able to do it) See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073435.